# How to change a .tex file's input encoding system (preferably to UTF-8)?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I've been trying to use the hyphenation patterns embedded in the file `dehyphtex.tex`, which is part of the `hyphen-german` package. Unfortunately, the file seems to be encoded in a system that's neither UTF-8 nor ASCII. Hundreds of words listed in the file contain characters (mostly vowels with Umlaute, but also e-with-sharp-accent and others) rendered as `�`. With MacTeX2012, I use TeXworks as my editor; this editor uses UTF8 as the default input encoding scheme. So far, the trial-and-error method of reloading the file using any of the several dozen alternative input encoding schemes that this editor is familiar with has produced no success.

I guess I could hand-edit the file to replace all `�` instances with the correct UTF8-encoded characters, but I'm hoping there's a more automated way of doing this. Does anyone know off-hand which input encoding scheme is used for this file, and/or does anyone know of a handy method to convert a file of unknown input encoding into a UTF8-encoded file?

Comment: it is a latin1 encoding , same as ISO 8859-15. With command `recode` you can change it

Comment: Open it with Emacs, go to the end of the file, replace `latin-1` with `utf-8` and save (a copy of) the file. :)

Comment: @Herbert - thanks! I didn't know about the correspondence between `latin-1` and `ISO-8859-15`...

Comment: @Herbert, Just to be precise, `latin1` is ISO-8859-1, while ISO-8859-15 is called `latin9`. Confusing, yes. Concerning accented letters both encodings are identical, the diffrences being in some infrequent characters and mostly in the encoding of the euro symbol, which was not present in `latin1` and later added in `latin9`

Comment: On a Unix system the `iconv` program does the conversion. A freeware program running also on Windows is [Charco](http://www.marblesoftware.com/Marble_Software/Charco.html)

Comment: In windows there is also `Notepad++`, a nice editor, which can read and save any encoding.

Comment: @Herbert - Please consider posting your comment as an answer; I'll gladly upvote & accept it.

Comment: @Mico: done and added an example code line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

it is a latin1 or latin9 encoding , same as ISO 8859-1 or 15. With command `recode` or `iconv` you can change it:

```
recode --diacritics --touch --verbose latin1..UTF-8 <file>
```

or

```
iconv -f LATIN1 -t UTF-8 inputfile.tex > outputfile.tex
```

Comment: Just for completeness (since I mentioned using this editor in my question): In the `TeXworks` editor, one can proceed as follows to change the file's encoding: (i) open the file in TeXworks; (ii) locate a box in the ribbon along the bottom of the editor window that (likely) says `UTF-8`; (iii) click on that box and select, e.g., `ISO-8859-15` from the menu that presents itself; (iv) click on the same box (which will now say "ISO-8859-15") and select the new menu choice, at the very top, that says `Reload using selected encoding`. Done!

Comment: @Mico: that is possible for a lot of other editors, but really dangerous if you mismatch the encodings ...

Comment: Indeed, if the old encoding isn't selected correctly, bad outcomes will likely follow.