# Comment Package: Problem when using German Special Character "ß" (Similar to "ss")

Tags: conditionals, input-encodings, comments, extended-characters

I am preparing a bilingual document and using the [`comment` package](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment) to distinguish between the two languages.

When I use the special character **ß** in a `comment` environment then I get an error message (`Undefined control sequence.`) although I use `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` correctly.

Outside of the `comment` environment the character works fine.

The document class seems not to matter - I have the problem with `scrbook` and `book`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    english,
    ngerman]
        {babel}

\usepackage{comment}

\includecomment{Version-DE}
\excludecomment{Version-EN}

\begin{document}
ß % <-- no problem here

\begin{Version-DE}
Version-DE
ß % <-- big problem here!
\end{Version-DE}

\begin{Version-EN}
Version-EN
\end{Version-EN}

\end{document}
```

I am not sure what **tags** to use here...

### For Future Reference

I have found some other packages that maybe could be an alternative:

- [multiaudience](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience) (recommended by the author of the `tagging` package Brent Longborough, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151688))
- [tagging](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tagging) --> seems to be pretty robust and flexible so far
- [srcredact](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/srcredact)
- [version](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/version)
- [versions](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/versions) (extra "s")
- [codesection](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/codesection)
- [xcomment](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcomment)
- [optional](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/optional)

Here's all the packages of this kind (con­di­tional type­set­ting) on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/topic/cond-comp

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to revert to the old-style `\ss` then ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hi, yes that's possible but I would like to avoid the work around :).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: `comment` doesn't work with “high bit set” characters. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding for a similar problem

Comment: Yes I get the same error

Comment: @egreg Do you know if there is an alternative approach like comment without that restriction? Or has your proposed work around some side effects? If not I go with your solution. Post it as an answer here if you want.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I'd say this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way forward -- hopefully feasible for you -- is to switch to either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and to load the `fontspec` package. All you will need to change in the document is (a) comment out (or delete) the instructions `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble and (b) add the instruction `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Of course, the document must be utf8-encoded, but these days utf8 is the default for most editors and web browsers. If the file isn't utf8-encoded at the moment, see the posting [How to change a .tex file's input encoding system (preferably to UTF-8)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87406/5001) for practical information on how to change the input encoding.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec} % <-- new

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{Version-DE}
\excludecomment{Version-EN}

\begin{document}
ß % <-- no problems here

\begin{Version-DE}
Version-DE
ß % <-- no more problem here either :-)
\end{Version-DE}

\begin{Version-EN}
Version-EN
\end{Version-EN}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain what is different? Does the write command not longer expand the special characters? Do oyu think that there is a drawback with solution of egreg (**\immediate\write\CommentStream{\unexpanded{#1}}%**)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner - I should have mentioned that the answer I've posted works with XeLaTeX too, and not just with LuaLaTeX. (I've edited the posting to rectify this omission.) I suspect it's the `fontspec` package that most of the heavy lifting, so to say, in the code I posted. One of the many nice things about LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX/fontspec is that the way a given character is encoded in utf8 (with either 1, 2, 3, or even 4 bytes) is immaterial for a great many uses cases. I'm afraid I can't comment knowledgeably on Enrico's method.