# Different PDFs from one .tex file

Tags: pdftex

I'm writing an article in LaTeX with theorem environments. Is it possible to create automatically one PDF file with whole article and in addition other PDF file only with theorems without the rest? Below I give an example file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} 

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem} 
This is theorem 1.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
This is lemma 2.
\end{lemma}

\begin{theorem}
This is theorem 3.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/multiple-pdf-generation-with-one-tex-file or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74243/automatically-create-two-pdf-output-files-from-one-tex-file (this one already duplicated, but it has interesting answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with the **`multiaudience` package**.

By commenting the `%\def\CurrentAudience` you control which parts are compiled. The `-` (minus) in `\begin{shownto}{-,myNotATheorem}` ivnerts the argument(s).

According to the manual you can also use this to define different versions in batch files, like `pdflatex "\def\CurrentAudience{SomeAudienceTag}\input{file}"`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=2mm]{standalone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma} 

%% The important package here
\usepackage{multiaudience}
% Define the possible audiences
\SetNewAudience{myNotATheorem}
\SetNewAudience{SomeThingElse}

%% Comment / Uncomment at free will
%\def\CurrentAudience{myNotATheorem}
\def\CurrentAudience{SomeThingElse}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\textbackslash CurrentAudience:} \textbf{\CurrentAudience}

\begin{theorem} 
This is theorem 1.
\end{theorem}

\begin{shownto}{-,myNotATheorem}
\begin{lemma}
This is lemma 2.
\end{lemma}
\end{shownto}

\begin{theorem}
This is theorem 3.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

- Now I see that I may have chosen confusing audience names :). But I hope that you still get it.
- See [Comment Package: Problem when using German Special Character "ß" (Similar to "ss")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318691) for more related packages.

Comment: Thank you! I have one more question. To make what I want I have to write \begin{shownto}{...} and \end{shownto}. Is it possible to define something like function in preamble so that I won't have to write this and I could only write \begin{theorem} ... \end{theorem} and LaTeX will know that when I uncomment \def\CurrentAudience{myNotATheorem} it should compile only theorems?

Comment: @Mayers I don't know. But with a decent text editor you can easily solve the problem with a simple search and replace :)